# Take a number argument and perserve its form?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to extend an interpreter I found online. The interpreter takes a number as an only argument and returns it as a string (`1 -> one, 2.3 -> two point three...` etc). I have extended its 'language' such that it includes the operator names (like "TIMES" and "PLUS").

Now, here's my problem. In order for these operators to hold, the only way I've found prudent to include is to instead of passing the argument as a number, to pass it as a string. For example, if I was to pass `3*5-23.2` to the function, I would want it to return `three TIMES five MINUS twenty three point two`. Instead, I get `negative eight point two`, which is the Evaluated form of the former argument.

Is there a way to manipulate an argument so that is becomes a string before it is evaluated? Or must I resort to forcing the user to input a String (and is this a bad thing?)?

## Edit 1

My code is a console-based one; the user accesses it like so:

```
> wordify(34)
"thirty four"
> wordify(3.4)
"three point four"
> wordify(Math.PI)
"three point one four one five nine two six..."  // omitted for convenience
```

If this were to be grabbed from an `<input>` element, I wouldn't have as much trouble (as the default would be a string to begin with), alas, this is not so.

Comment: We need to see some code: the interpreter (possibly just the part exhibiting the problem) and your extensions to it.  Otherwise we're just guessing at what you might possibly be able to do to solve your problem.

Comment: Suppose they pass you `some_variable` or `Math.sqrt(4)`. What should happen?

Comment: @user2357112 If some_variable is a string, my current code will return "not a number"; Math.sqrt(4) returns "two".

Comment: We definitely need to see how you are getting the "argument" ... input from an `<input>` tag is already a string and might be parsed before you work with it.

Comment: @rfornal It's a simple function that the user accesses with JavaScript coding. (like, they would type `5.32` to get an answer).

Comment: @ConorO'Brien: What *should* happen? What would your code do if passed `Math.sqrt(4)`, if your code worked the way you wanted it to?

Comment: this is probably impossible unless you let the user pass the argument as a string, e.g. `'3-4'` instead of just `3-4`. Think about why this is this way: Imagine if it was possible to stop it from executing immediately. Then, your function would be passed, say `3-4` as a number. But if that qualified as a `Number` type, things would turn bad pretty quickly

Comment: @user2357112 Oh, I see... Well, I didn't think about that (darn my lack of planning). I guess I'd use a RegExp to grab all methods and functions (something like `/(.*\..*\(.+\))/`) and see if they return a number result, or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other way than passing a string to the function as all the arguments have to be evaluated before the function call can be performed. Why do you consider expecting a string input a bad thing? If the value is derived from a HTML input field, it will always be a string unless it is explicitly evaluated.

Comment: That's the thing--it isn't from an `<input>` element. And to pass it as a string would mean more typing for the user (not entirely sure _how_ bad this is, though).

Comment: So the user is the programmer in that case, right? The programmer must be aware of the fact that a function call will cause all the arguments to be evaluated first. That's a basic concept applied by most of the scripting and programming languages. Is it really that much work to put the input between two quotes?